# GWT Web Application project, with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt

I've made a Google Web Application Project in Eclipse and am now running into problems as I need to use from a server side point of view, with Hibernate with MySQL.  I've just been told that Google Web Application projects can't run Hibernate connections to MySQL as they're deployed projects.

What's the best way for me to migrate this project somehow so it runs on say Glassfish and just uses GWT for the client side technologies that can then use Hibernate and MySQL, rather than actually being deployed?

Thanks,

David

Comment: **Google App Engine** projects can't use Hibernate and MySQL.

Comment: Yes, but I'm just wanting to know how to migrate my project.

Comment: Just wanted to point that your wording is incorrect: "GWT projects can't run Hibernate connections to MySQL as they're deployed projects". It's because it's a GAE project that it doesn't work. Not because it's a GWT project.

Comment: Ah, it appears to be a "Google Web Application" rather than GAE, are those actually the same?

Comment: Yep. A Google Web Application is meant to be deployed on Google App Engine.

Comment: hmm I didn't know that term - now I found that it's common in Eclipse world :)

Comment: So to clarify, I need to create a new Project as a Dynamic Web Project rather than a Google Web Application, so it will run in Tomcat and then write the GWT code in this?  Is that correct?

Comment: I *think* you need two projects: one for the client-side, which is a GWT project. Another one for the server-side, which is a web project. But I don't know eclipse and the google plugin sufficiently well to say that it's not possible to have a project with the two facets (GWT + web project). Your question is badly formulated. It should have the eclipse tag, and ask how to build a web + GWT project in Eclipse.

Comment: Ah, managed to do it all in the GoogleWebApplication in the end, without using GAE, I'll write a blog about it at some point because it was a pain in the arse!!  But now means I can deploy my GWA onto Tomcat :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot* access database from client-side directly.

GWT translates your client-side java code into Javascript which runs in browser; there is no way to directly access JDBC.

You will have to employ server-side which will handle your DB persistence. Your client can communicate via [GWT-RPC](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html), [JSON](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSON.html), [XML](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsXML.html), or any other protocol - but the database connection part will always reside on server.

Note that the server part does not need to be in Java - it can [use PHP](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSONphp.html) or any other technology, as long as it understands the javascript generated out of your app.

Comment: Hi, I've editted my code slightly, I'm not calling any JDBC from my GWT code, I'm calling it from the server in the ASync but I want to use a local server (Tomcat?) rather than the deployed one so I can use my own persistance handling rather than the Google ones.

Comment: seems like you talk about appengine application, but there is no single word indicating that in your question

Comment: I think you are facing a cross-scripting issue, because you want the server to run on different `host:port` than your client app., is that the case ? If the GWT server was in your network, you could overcome this with a simple proxy, but I am afraid that there is no simple way to do this from appengine server :(

Comment: sorry I meant [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) not cross-scripting